# How to update the parent page from the modal popup in real time

Tags: jquery, html, requirejs, durandal

i have a problem. I have a view with a list of persons with some details. When i click on that list a bootstrap modal pops-up with the details(like an edit page except it'a a modal). I want to be able to make changes in the modal and at the same time the parent page should update with the new data i entered. So the parent page should update without the user pressing a button in the modal.
This is the html for the parent page:

```
<section id="sessions-view" class="view">
    <header>

        <h3 class="page-title" data-bind="text: title"></h3>   
        <i class="icon-asterisk" data-bind="visible:hasChanges"></i>
        <div class="article-counter">
            <address data-bind="text: domainUser().length"></address>
            <address>found</address>
        </div>
    </header>
    <section class="view-list" data-bind="foreach: domainUser">
        <article class="article-left-content">
            <div class="domainUser-brief" title="Go to user domain details">

                <span data-bind="text: firstName"></span>
                <span data-bind="text: lastName"></span>
                <span data-bind="text: email"></span>
                <span data-bind="text: age"></span>
                <span data-bind="text:city"></span>

            </div>
        </article>
    </section>


</section>
```

The js for the parent page:

```
define(['services/datacontext', 'durandal/plugins/router', 'durandal/modalDialog', 'durandal/app'],
    function (datacontext, router, modalDialog, app) {
        var domainUser = ko.observableArray();

        var activate = function () {
            var result = datacontext.getDomainUsers(domainUser);
            return result;
        };
var hasChanges = ko.computed(function() {
            return datacontext.hasChanges();
        });
 var bindEventToList = function (rootSelector, selector, callback, eventName) {
            var eName = eventName || 'click';
            $(rootSelector).on(eName, selector, function () {
                var domainUserData = ko.dataFor(this);
                callback(domainUserData);
                return false;
            });
        };


        var vm = {
            activate: activate,
            refresh: refresh,
            domainUser: domainUser,
            hasChanges: hasChanges,
            viewAttached: viewAttached,
            title: 'Domain Users',
        };
        return vm;
    });
```

The html of the modal:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>

    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <section id="session-view" class="view">
           <h3 class="page-title" data-bind="text: title"></h3> <i class="icon-asterisk" data-bind="visible: hasChanges" ></i>

    <div data-bind="with: domainUser"> 
        <div class="details-left">
            <label for="title">First Name</label>
                <input id="title" data-bind="value: firstName" placeholder="First Name"/>
            <label for="title">Last Name</label>
                <input id="Text1" data-bind="value: lastName" placeholder="Last Name"/>
            <label for="title">Email</label>
                <input id="Text2" data-bind="value: email" placeholder="Email"/>
            <label for="title">Age</label>
                <input id="Text4" data-bind="value: age" placeholder="Age"/>
            <label for="title">City</label>
                <input id="Text3" data-bind="value: city" placeholder="City"/>

        </div>

    </div>
</section>
</div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" data-bind="click: cancel">Close</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" data-bind=" click: save" aria-hidden="true">Save changes</button>

    </div>
</div>
```

And the .js for the modal

```
define(['services/datacontext',
        'durandal/plugins/router',
        'durandal/system',
        'durandal/app',
        'services/logger'],
    function (datacontext, router, system, app, logger) {
        var domainUser = ko.observable();
 var activate = function (activationData) {
            var id = parseInt(activationData.id);
            return datacontext.getDomainUserById(id, domainUser);
        };
 var hasChanges = ko.computed(function () {
            return datacontext.hasChanges();
        });
var cancel = function () {
            datacontext.cancelChanges();
            this.modal.close();
        };

        var canSave = ko.computed(function () {
            return hasChanges() && !isSaving();
        });

        var save = function() {
            isSaving(true),
            this.modal.close();

            return datacontext.saveChanges().fin(complete);};
 function complete() {
                isSaving(false);
            }
var vm = {
            activate: activate,
            cancel: cancel,
            canSave: canSave,
            hasChanges: hasChanges,
            save: save,
            domainUser: domainUser,
            title: 'Domain user details'
        };
        return vm;
});
```

Comment: Maybe you can use the `data` tag for all your inputs in the modal. I suppose you can catch the parent that has been clicked to open the modal. In each data attribute, reffer to to the corresponding parent attribute in the main page. Make function like `$("#modal input").change(function())}...`. Each time a field is changed in the modal, get the corresponding in the main page and update its value.

Comment: ty for your responses. I'm building a SPA based on john papa's tutorial Code CAmper JumpStart. I'm using durandal.js, breeze.js, bootstrap, sammy.js, knockout.js

Comment: after some reading i came to the conclusion that i can use knockoutjs's plugin for mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Since your `domainUser` variable in the parent view is a `ko.observableArray` containing all your users, all you need to do is pass the `ko.observable` of the user you want to edit to the `activate()` method of your popup dialog view. Then you don't have to do an ajax call in your modal view to get the user; thus, saving you a round-trip to the server. You almost have the right idea with `ko.dataFor()`, except that function returns the raw data, not the observable its associated with in your array.

You already have all the data loaded on the parent, so leverage that advantage. :)